# JPA insert transaction concurrency

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, transactions

I have more of theoretical question:
When data gets inserted into a database? is it after persist or after commit is called? Because I have a problem with unique keys (manually generated) - they get duplicate. I'm thinking this is due multiple users inserting data simultaneously into a same table.

**UPDATE 1:**

I generate keys in my application. Keys example: '123456789123','123456789124','123456789125'...

Key field is varchar type, because there are lot of old keys (I can't delete or change them) like 'VP123456','VP15S3456'. Another problem, that after inserting them into one database, these keys have to be inserted in another database. And I don't know what are DB sequences and Atomic objects..

**UPDATE 2:**

These keys are used in finance documents and not as database keys. So they must be unique, but they are not used anywhere in programming as object keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "...these keys have to be inserted in another database.". Are they used as a key there as well? Is it really necessary that those "keys" are your technical database keys?

Comment: I updated (update 2) my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a Singleton that takes care of generating your keys. Make sure you can only get a new id once the singleton has initialized with the latest value from the database.

To safeguard you from incomplete inserts into the two databases I would suggest you try to use [XA transactions](https://www.google.se/search?q=xa+transaction). This will allow you to have  all-or-nothing inserts and updates. So if any of the operations on any of the databases fails, everything will be rolled back. Of course there is a downside of XA transactions; they are quite slow and not all databases and database drivers support it.

Comment: Does this solution protect from multiusers? I mean if two or more users are inserting data to the same table at a same time on different computers using this app?

Comment: Well, it depends of course what you mean by "app". If your program runs on a server and several clients connect to it, then yes, it will (if done right) protect from concurrency problems. If you have several programs that run on each user's PC and just connect to the same databases, then it will give you the same problems you had to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. I see now that one and only solution to avoid duplicates is to generate that field on new row insertion (my app is standalone desktop app without a server). I can't do that so I will think of some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate these keys? Have you tried using sequences in DB or atomic objects?

I'm asking because it is normal to populate DB concurrently.

EDIT1:

You can write a method that returns new keys based on atomic counter, this way you'll know that anytime you request a new key you receive a **unique** key. This strategy may and will lead to some keys being discarded but it is a small price to pay, unless it is a requirement that keys in the database are sequential.

```
private AtomicLong counter; //initialized somewhere else.

public String getKey(){
  return "VP" + counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

And here's some help on DB Sequences in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm), [MySql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm), etc.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to generate the keys in your application. There are a lot of things you need to take care of. Using an atomic datatype is only the beginning. Your have to be absolutely sure that only one instance of the id generating class is running at any given time. Furthermore you have to take care of proper initialization and such.

If humanly possible let the database take care of this. Either using a sequence (best way to do it) or, if you need to do strange things generating the ids, using a stored procedure (which will probably use a sequence internally as well).

Comment: Problem is I can't change many aspects of database it's too complicated to explain why - I just not allowed to do that. And these keys are generated with some logic behind it - new row is an item, witch belongs to one group. The group has it's own key (again not a database key) witch is the beginning of item key...